# If I have multiple checkboxes in a form how can I pass all the checkboxes that are currently checked?

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

This is my code:

```
<form action="test.php" method="post">
    <input type="checkbox" value="value 1" onClick="updateCards(this.value);">
    <input type="checkbox" value="value 2" onClick="updateCards(this.value);">
    <input type="checkbox" value="value 3" onClick="updateCards(this.value);">
    <input type="checkbox" value="value 4" onClick="updateCards(this.value);">
    <input type="checkbox" value="value 5" onClick="updateCards(this.value);">
</form>
```

How can I get all the checkboxes that are currently checked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
<form id="myform" action="test.php" method="post">
```

Then

```
function getChcked(){
    var form = document.getElementById('myform');
    var chks = form.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]');
    var checked = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < chks.length; i++){
        if(chks[i].checked){
            checked.push(chks[i].value)
        }
    }
    return checked;
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/n6fwY/)

Comment: Is there a way to get the values?

Comment: instead of pushing `checked.push(chks[i])`, push `checked.push(chks[i].value)`

Comment: One more question, is there a way to get the form by name or id?

Comment: @rotaercz if you can assign one then you can use id

Answer (score 1):

Two quick ways could be give your form element an ID.  Get a reference to it and loop through all it's children element(which is all of your checkboxes) and check what the value of the checked property is.

You could also give all of your checkboxes a class name and use `document.getElementsByClassName` and then loop through the results to check the checked property.  However I think this second method may not be supported in IE8, don't quote me on that but I would use the first method.

Something like this

```
<form action="test.php" method="post" id="myForm">
  <input type="checkbox" value="value 1" onClick="updateCards(this.value);">
  <input type="checkbox" value="value 2" onClick="updateCards(this.value);">
  <input type="checkbox" value="value 3" onClick="updateCards(this.value);">
  <input type="checkbox" value="value 4" onClick="updateCards(this.value);">
  <input type="checkbox" value="value 5" onClick="updateCards(this.value);">
</form>

var getValues = function() {
  var nodes = document.getElementById("myForm").children;
  var checkedValues = [],
      length = nodes.length,
      i = 0;

  for(i;i<length;i++){
    if(nodes[i].checked)
    checkedValues.push(nodes[i].value);
  }

  return checkedValues;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function getCheckedBoxes(chkboxName) {
  var checkboxes = document.getElementsByName(chkboxName);
  var checkboxesChecked = [];
  // loop over them all
  for (var i=0; i<checkboxes.length; i++) {
     // And stick the checked ones onto an array...
     if (checkboxes[i].checked) {
        checkboxesChecked.push(checkboxes[i]);
     }
  }
  // Return the array if it is non-empty, or null
  return checkboxesChecked.length > 0 ? checkboxesChecked : null;
}

// Call as
var checkedBoxes = getCheckedBoxes("mycheckboxes");
```

[**Live DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/vaibviad/dvCmR/217/)

**Also try this one**

```
$("#clickme").click(function(e){


    var selected = $("#checkboxes input:checked").map(function(i,el){return el.name;}).get();


    alert("selected = [" + selected + "]\nas string = \"" + selected.join(";") + "\"");


});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a little shortcut way to do the same:

```
var nodeArray = document.querySelectorAll('form input:checked'), 
    i = nodeArray.length, selected = [];
while(i--) selected.push(nodeArray[i].value);
```

Answer (score 0):

This would be a lot simpler if you just use jQuery:

```
  function GetChecked()
  {
     return $("input:checked");
  }
```